# How do you get your weapons out, in Grand Theft Auto 5 races?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

How do you get your weapons out during races, in Grand Theft Auto 5?

I am playing on Xbox One.

Comment: Wow, this question has been received pretty harshly. Don't get discouraged, Tom! I'm guessing downvotes are for lack of research, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use your weapons on GTA Races- they are a special type of race where you can exit your car and use weapons.

On that kind of race, just hold down l2 like you would on freeroam.

Comment: Or LT, if your playing on xbox